# Codeigniter login page missing

Tags: codeigniter

i was copying my friend's project that was created using codeigniter.

i copied all files from her www folder including mysql data and paste to my www folder and mysql data, but when i try run on my localhost it show "Not Found The requested URL simrm/login was not found on this server.

i'm newbie using codeigniter,so how to fix this problem?

Comment: You probably didn't copy the hidden .htaccess file. You need that to be able to access URL's like this: `/simrm/login` instead of: `index.php/simrm/login`.

Comment: can i create htaccess file for that?

Comment: Yes, you can create a `.htaccess` file for that. See: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ohh i think your are new in codeigniter...
You have to used the `.htaccess` file to get rid from index.php,

Or you can redirect it by using `redirect(base_url().'index.php/login');`

Comment: thx for all and special for hammed for correct answer. but i still have problem on next step. login page was opened and there nothing happened when i press submit button. my form like this <form method="post" action=<?php echo site_url('login/process_form'); ?>>. process_form is function in login.php model.

Answer (score 0):

You can check baseurl path (ie, path to your project) whether you have given it correctly in config.php. 
Path to config.php is `application/config/config.php` or inside `system/application/config/config.php`

`$config['base_url']    = 'your_project_url'`

Comment: i was do that $config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/myproject/'; but still error. the page not found when redirect to login n other page